# condition in regular expression qt

Tags: c++, qt5

I wrote a regular expression for find the scopes('{'|'}'). I want to find the scopes that wasn't  commented, but I don't understand where I have mistake. Here are a fragment of code:

```
    while (start >= 0 && end >=0) {
        start = text.indexOf("\n", start);
        end  = text.indexOf(QRegExp("^.*[{](?!=[//]|[/*]|[*]))"),start);
        end2  = text.indexOf(QRegExp("^.*[}](?!=[//]|[/*]|[*]))"), start);
        if (end < end2) {
            text.replace(end,"\n{\n");
        }
        else  text.replace(end2,"\n}\n");
        ++start;
   }
```

For example, we have some text:

```
//dfsdkfj ksjdfksjdf {  <- this symbol should be skipped
public SystemBlock()
{  //<- this symbol should be found. 
    this.producer = "none";
    this.motherBoard = "none";
    this.processor = "none";
    this.ram = "none";
    this.gpu = "none";
    this.price = 0;
    this.eventSupport = null;
}
```

Comment: At first, escape curly braces: `\\{` and'\\}'. They may be interpreted as quantificators.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is generally impossible to correctly parse C++ code with regular expressions. Think about nested comments, line continuations, strings containing `"//"`, `"/*"` etc.!

Secondly, it is generally hard to have a regex *not* match something. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) for more details.

But *your specific example* can be parsed with a regex like this: `^(?!(//|/\*))*{`
:

```
    end  = text.indexOf(QRegExp("^(?!(//|/\\*))*\\{"),start);
    end2  = text.indexOf(QRegExp("^(?!(//|/\\*))*\\}"), start);
```

Comment: thanks  for your answer, but it still doesn't work.  It expression always returned -1.

Comment: Also qt regexp doesn't parse "{" as  lonely symbol, we must use sequence scopes "[{]" and  symbol '{'  will correctly parsed after that this operation.

Comment: Then escape it: `\\{`

Comment: thanks at all, I escaped scopes, but  without results.